# jboss 7 AS datasource for sqlserver

Tags: jboss, datasource, jboss7.x, sqljdbc

I run jboss in standalone mode and have set my datasource in the `standalone.xml` to the following:

```
<datasource jndi-name="MyDenaliDS" pool-name="MyDenaliDs_Pool" enabled="true" jta="true" 
                                                   use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>
        jdbc:sqlserver://myip:1433;databaseName=mydb;integratedSecurity=true
    </connection-url>
    <driver>
        sqljdbc
    </driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>
            username
        </user-name>
        <password>
            password
        </password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="sqljdbc" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
        <driver-class>
            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
        </driver-class>
    </driver>                    
</drivers>
```

in the folder `%jbosshome%\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\` I have the `sqljdb4.jar` and the following `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/> 
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/> 
     </dependencies>
</module>
```

When I start the jboss it gives me the following error:

```
> New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:    service
> jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc (missing)
```

Anyone know what I've done incorrect or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got the same error like you before

instead of %jbosshome%\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\

try %jbosshome%\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main

and put the .jar of the jdbc driver and the module.xml overthere.

Comment: I did this and it still does not work for me in JBoss 7.0.2.Final

Answer (score 14):

using Jboss AS 7.1.1, as well as putting the module in `%jbosshome%\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main`  I had to make a slight change to the xml - the driver element in standalone.xml should be :

```
 <driver name="sqljdbc" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
      <driver-class>
           com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      </driver-class>
 </driver>
```

and the module.xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

Comment: I'm still getting 14:55:59,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) Service status report
   New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc (missing)

Comment: Cheers for that – it helped! The only thing I changed was the <driver> tag within the standalone.xml to be:
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc"/>
                </drivers>

Answer (score 5):

With Jboss 7.1.1 I managed to get it working without specifying module.

Just put sqljdbc4.jar into deployment directory:
%JBOSSHOME%\standalone\deployments

Configuration needed for datasource in standalone.xml is as follows:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myPool" pool-name="myPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=myName;</connection-url>
    <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>myUser</user-name>
        <password>myPassword</password>
    </security>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Comment: Using the jar file name as driver name and skipping the <drivers> part also worked for me. The SQL Server driver is JDBC Type 4 compliant and it is sufficient to deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

I used this configuration and it worked OK on AS7

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/stagingDS" pool-name="stagingDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://linp-sqlrpt-01;databaseName=pmdm</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>username</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
 </datasource>

<drivers>
    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.jdbc">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

Of course if you're not using the distributed DataSource you can configure the regular driver class as previously defined.

The module file looks like this.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.jdbc">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
       <module name="javax.api"/>
       <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
       <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deploying JDBC jar file (e.g. sqljdbc41.jar) by admin console should allow to select and use it when defining a new data source.

Answer (score 0):

this is the work for me.
in JBOSS 7, MSSQL JDBC driver 6, type 4, file name:sqljdbc42.jar

- Install the driver name:sqljdbc42.jar in [JBoss HOME]\modules\com\microsoft\main
- add under the same directory module.xml with content below

  ```
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft">
  <resources>
  <resource-root path="sqljdbc42.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
  </module>
  ```
- insert datasource definition to  standalone.xml in block `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0"> <datasources>` as below

  ```
  <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/iwebDS" pool-name="MSSQLDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://172.24.17.52:1803;DatabaseName=IWEB_IWEBSIT</connection-url>
  <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
  <driver>sqlserver2008</driver>
  <pool>
  <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
  <initial-pool-size>10</initial-pool-size>
  <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
  <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
  </pool>
  <security>
  <user-name>[sqlserver user]</user-name>
  <password>[sqlserver password]</password>
  </security>
  <validation>
  <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
  <background-validation>true</background-validation>
  </validation>
  </datasource>
  ```
- insert driver definition to standalone.xml in block `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0"> <drivers>` as below

  ```
  <driver name="sqlserver2008" module="com.microsoft">
  <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
  </driver>
  ```

ps: "sqlserver2008" is the name as you wish.